# Analysis of categorical variables based on three dependent dropdowns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'id': {0: 84, 1: 84, 2: 84, 3: 84, 4: 124},
               'Version': { 0: 'SemVer4', 1: 'Timestamps', 2: 'Snapshots', 3: 'Names', 4: 'Numbered Versions'},
               'server_Version': {0: 'v1', 1: 'v2', 2: 'api/v1', 3: '1.1.0', 4: 'v4'},
               'owner': {0: 'vmware', 1:'microsoft', 2: 'nasa', 3: 'swagger-API', 4:'sqaas'},
               'repo_name': {0: 'container-service-extension', 1: 'azure-rest-api-specs', 2: 'api.nasa.gov', 3: 'swagger-ui', 4: 'sqaas'},
               'filepath':{0: 'openapi.yaml', 1: 'dapper.json', 2: 'dockstore-webservice/src/main/resources/openapi3/openapi.yaml', 3: 'api/cmd/kubermatic-api/swagger.json', 4: 'cmd/spec/openapi.jsonsqaas'}})
```

I want to create a visualization that takes as input three dependent dropdowns: **owner**, **repo name** and **filepath**. The relation between these three is that owner represents the main API name,reponames are the names of the repositories under the owner and filepaths are the names for different operations within the selected repo.

My desired output for the dropdowns is like this:
[image: []

I was able to create these dropdowns in Elasticsearch, but the issue arises in analysing the data, since some fields are not properly parsed in kibana.

The visualization through which I want the dropdown filtering applied is:
[image]

```
fig = px.scatter(df.query("owner=='swagger-api'"), x="Year", y="Month", color="Version", text="server_version")
fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right")
fig.show()
```

What I am doing here is for over the years and months, I find out which API versions and which server versions have been used, but as I am doing it for one owner as you can see in the code, I want some filtering that displays it for specific repo and filepath as well.

I am currently using Plotly for my visualizations, and I am quite new to this library. If there is any other library, that can help me achieve this, do let me know. Any help or suggestions on how to proceed with this is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think in `plotly-python`, you will have difficulty making the dropdowns dependent. It sounds like what you want is for the options in one dropdown to affect the options available in other dropdowns (i.e. selecting `vmware` should constrain the other available dropdowns). however, if you are interested, such a solution is definitely available `plotly-dash` because of `callbacks` (dropdowns are "aware" about what option has been selected in another dropdown), and I would be happy to write up a solution for you later

Comment: Ahh I see, yes if you could help me out with a solution in plotly-dash that would be really helpful for me! I am still struggling with this issue

Comment: My idea for the dropdown was suppose we consider vmware, there are like 5 repositories under that, and then under one specific repo, there are a number of api files. I want the scatter plot dimensions to change according to whatever option is selected.

Comment: that makes sense – this can be achieved with a callback function that takes the input/state of other dropdowns as inputs and updates the current dropdown accordingly – i've done something similar before

Comment: Could you possibly guide me on how can i code this, as I have never worked with plotly-dash before.

Comment: Sure I can create an example using the sample data you've provided. where are the repo names coming from?

Comment: I updated the post with the reponame column in the dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249500/discussion-between-derek-o-and-brie-merryweather).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you want the dropdowns to be dependent, the dropdowns have to be aware of the state of the other dropdowns – this isn't possible in `plotly`, but this is possible in `plotly-dash` since [callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) are supported.

To do this, we can write an update function that takes all possible selections for your three dropdowns, and updates all other dropdowns based on subsetting your `df`. And I figured that in the same function, it would make sense to update the figure accordingly as well.

The only tricky part is that when you make a selection from one dropdown but don't make selections from the others, you get `None` as an input, but if you clear the selection(s) from a dropdown you get `[]` as an input, so your update function needs to account for that situation. And if you are clear the selections from all dropdowns, you probably want all possible dropdown options to show up again – this possibility is also accounted for.

I also extended your sample `df` to include multiple rows for some of the dropdowns just to check that the dash app still works for this situation. There might be some edge cases I haven't accounted for, but for now this solution seems to be working.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, ctx

df = pd.DataFrame ({'id': {0: 84, 1: 84, 2: 84, 3: 84, 4: 124, 5:1, 6:1},
               'Version': { 0: 'SemVer4', 1: 'Timestamps', 2: 'Snapshots', 3: 'Names', 4: 'Numbered Versions', 5: 'test', 6: 'test'},
               'server_Version': {0: 'v1', 1: 'v2', 2: 'api/v1', 3: '1.1.0', 4: 'v4', 5: 'v5', 6: 'v5'},
               'owner': {0: 'vmware', 1:'microsoft', 2: 'nasa', 3: 'swagger-API', 4:'sqaas',5:'vmware',6:'nasa'},
               'Year': {0: '2018', 1:'2020', 2:'2018', 3:'2019', 4:'2019', 5:'2021',6:'2021'},
               'Month': {0: 1, 1:6, 2:2, 3:4, 4:5, 5:5, 6:10},
               'repo_name': {0: 'container-service-extension', 1: 'azure-rest-api-specs', 2: 'api.nasa.gov', 3: 'swagger-ui', 4: 'sqaas', 5:'vmware-test',6:'nasa-test'},
               'filepath':{0: 'openapi.yaml', 1: 'dapper.json', 2: 'dockstore-webservice/src/main/resources/openapi3/openapi.yaml', 3: 'api/cmd/kubermatic-api/swagger.json', 4: 'cmd/spec/openapi.jsonsqaas', 5:'vmware-test-path',6:'nasa-test-path'}})

df = df.sort_values(by='Year')

## default is to show all data
fig = px.scatter(df, x="Year", y="Month", color="Version", text="server_Version")
fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right")

app = Dash(__name__)

## three dependent dropdowns: owner, repo name and filepath
dropdown_selections = {
    category:df[category].unique().tolist() 
    for category in ['owner','repo_name','filepath']
}

dropdown_id_to_col_mapping = {
    'owner-dropdown':'owner',
    'repo-name-dropdown': 'repo_name',
    'filepath-dropdown': 'filepath'
}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    dropdown_selections['owner'], 
                    id='owner-dropdown',
                    placeholder="Select owner",
                    style={"display": "inline-block", "width": "220px"},
                    multi=True,
                ),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    dropdown_selections['repo_name'], 
                    id='repo-name-dropdown',
                    placeholder="Select repo name",
                    style={"display": "inline-block", "width": "220px", 'padding-left': '5px'}, 
                    multi=True
                ),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    dropdown_selections['filepath'], 
                    id='filepath-dropdown', 
                    placeholder="Select filepath",
                    style={"display": "inline-block", "width": "220px", 'padding-left': '5px'},
                    multi=True
                )
            ],
            style={"padding": "10px", 'padding-left': '6%'},
        ),
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='px-scatter-fig')
    ]
)

## callback so that a selection from one figure updates the others
@app.callback(
    Output('owner-dropdown', 'options'),
    Output('repo-name-dropdown', 'options'),
    Output('filepath-dropdown', 'options'),
    Output('px-scatter-fig', 'figure'),
    Input('owner-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('repo-name-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('filepath-dropdown', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_dropdowns(owner_selection, repo_name_selection, filepath_selection):
    # print(f'you selected: {owner_selection}, {repo_name_selection}, {filepath_selection}')
    dropdown_selected = ctx.triggered_id
    col_selected = dropdown_id_to_col_mapping[dropdown_selected]

    change_dropdowns = ['owner-dropdown','repo-name-dropdown','filepath-dropdown']
    change_dropdowns.remove(dropdown_selected)

    ## if you clear ALL dropdown selections, then we reset all dropdowns
    ## (and this will skip all of the following other if statements)
    if (owner_selection == []) & (repo_name_selection == []) & (filepath_selection == []):
        owner_selection = dropdown_selections['owner']
        repo_name_selection = dropdown_selections['repo_name']
        filepath_selection = dropdown_selections['filepath']

    ## if any dropdowns are cleared or not selected, we want all possible selections to return
    ## this is because if we clear some but not all dropdowns, the conditions from other dropdowns remain in place
    ## and the new dropdown selections are calculated from the subset dataframe and should be correct
    if owner_selection == []:
        owner_selection = dropdown_selections['owner']
    if repo_name_selection == []:
        repo_name_selection = dropdown_selections['repo_name']
    if filepath_selection == []:
        filepath_selection = dropdown_selections['filepath']

    if owner_selection == None:
        owner_selection = dropdown_selections['owner']
    if repo_name_selection == None:
        repo_name_selection = dropdown_selections['repo_name']
    if filepath_selection == None:
        filepath_selection = dropdown_selections['filepath']
    
    ## subset the dataframe by dropdown conditions
    df_subset = df[
        df['owner'].isin(owner_selection)
        & df['repo_name'].isin(repo_name_selection)
        & df['filepath'].isin(filepath_selection)
    ]

    owner_selection = df_subset['owner'].unique().tolist()
    repo_name_selection = df_subset['repo_name'].unique().tolist()
    filepath_selection = df_subset['filepath'].unique().tolist()

    fig_update = px.scatter(df_subset, x="Year", y="Month", color="Version", text="server_Version")
    fig_update.update_traces(textposition="bottom right")

    return owner_selection, repo_name_selection, filepath_selection, fig_update

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]